# 404 error when attempting to install type information for node or express

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, typescript-typings

Following a basic tutorial to move to typescript.

However when I attempt to install type information, by

```
npm install --save @types/node
```

or

```
npm install --save @types/express
```

I get 404 errors all over the place and fail.  Obviously something basic is wrong, since I see this package listed at npm.

Answer (score 0):

This was on windows, with npm installed through Chocolatey.  Uninstalling node and npm from choco, and reinstalling via the package from the node website seems to have fixed it.